# How to wait the upload function return true(the object in server exist.) to do next? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, image-uploading, wait

I have an upload image function in "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo".
when I pick photo done, start uploading image.
But when I in editing View, I click the "choose" button, the view doesn't dismiss that look like locked, press anything doesn't work.  
I guess my check sever function whether have the image or not, make it locked.
Sorry I'm beginner and already search the stack overflow,I dont know what answer can solve this problem.

```
   let albumPicker = UIImagePickerController()
   albumPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
   albumPicker.delegate = self
   albumPicker.allowsEditing = true
   self.present(albumPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


 internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
    let imageName:String = uuid + ".jpg"
    let documentsPath = NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/")
    let imagePath = documentsPath.appending(imageName)
    let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)

    photoImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    if picker.sourceType == .camera {

        photoImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photoImage!, nil, nil, nil)
    }

    showLoadingView()

    hideLoadingView {

        //uploading 
        let objectKey:String = imageName
        oss.uploadObjectAsync(imageUrl, objectKey: objectKey)

        oss.checkObjectExist(objectKey: objectKey) 
        //this is check server object
        //First,I want to check the object exist ,and send message 

        let message = "http:104.168.1.111/\(imageName)"
        self.sendMessage(message: message)
        self.tableView.scrollToBottom()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //sometimes donesnt work.
    }
}
```

```
var client:OSSClient?

func checkObjectExist(objectKey:String) {

    let put:OSSPutObjectRequest = OSSPutObjectRequest()

    put.bucketName = ossBucketName
    put.objectKey = objectKey
    do {
        try client?.doesObjectExist(inBucket: put.bucketName, objectKey: put.objectKey)

    } catch {
        //debug(object: error)
        print("*****ERROR HERE: \(error)")
    }
}
```

"doesObjectExist" document says

```
 open func doesObjectExist(inBucket bucketName: String, objectKey: String) throws

 return YES                     Object exist
 return NO && *error = nil      Object don't exist
 return NO && *error != nil     error
```

Thanks.

Comment: If app is frozen then press the pause button to see the code expecting when the app is frozen. Also see which thread the code is getting executed in. Use main thread / main queue only for UI tasks. Rest of the tasks like uploading must need to be done in the background thread / queue

Comment: I guess the check object function return false make me image picker doesn't dismiss,so i look for waiting return true method.